# Why do faces split

Tags: texturing, faces

What am I doing wrong...
Whenever I make something in blender and then create an uv map and ao map, I upload the item in world. Then the texture I made for it doesn't come out well and see that all the faces are suddenly diagonally split in half.
Why is this and is there a way to prevent this? Because I can never use textures I made like this.

Comment: a picture with an example would be helpful.

Comment: some formats can only save triangulated meshes. Which formats do you use and what do you mean by "upload[ing] the item in world"?

Comment: Also related to "world" - the name of the engine would be quite helpful.

Comment: I export it to collada and use Second Life.